# Importing a function (by name) from a filename

Tags: python, import, python-2.7, filenames

I'm writing a code tracer that uses the `trace` module. In order to use the trace module, I need to first be able to call the function in question.

I have been successful in importing the module which contains the function definition, by using `imp` as follows:

```
mod = imp.load_source(os.path.basename(fpath).rpartition('.py')[0], fpath)
```

where `fpath` is the path to the module that needs to be imported.

I do not know ahead of time, what function/class I need to import from `mod`. This is identified in a `str` variable (let's call it `var` for the sake of this example).

For example, `fpath` could be `'/Users/username/.../myPythonModule.py'` and `var` could be `'foo'`

How would I go about importing `foo` from `mod`?
I'm on python2.7, if it matters

Comment: I like how you declared `var` and then gave it the value `foo` without any code.

Comment: @Keyser: Good catch! Hope the edit clarifies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have imported the module as object `mod`, and `var` is a string containing the name of the function you want, you can do `getattr(mod, var)` to get the function (or class, value, etc.) of that name from the module.

Comment: I didn't realize `getattr` could be used like that. I should have known. Awesome catch! Accepting in 8 minutes, 7:59, 7:58...